# How to select cell on UICollectionView load

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am loading a collection view where upon cell selection the cell draws a circle (UIView + CGRect) on it's view to indicate the selection. This collection view represents a calendar and I want the first date to be selected when initially loaded. For the life of me cannot get this is load properly, either the code for the selection does not fire, or the circle get's drawn incorrectly because the outlet's have not been initialized on the cell (the circle's position is reliant on the position of a label).

This is my select method on the cell, that is called on cell selection from the collection view data source:

```
func select() {
    circleView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(dateLabel.center.x - (dateLabel.frame.size.width / 2), dateLabel.center.y - (dateLabel.frame.size.height / 2), 40, 40))
    circleView!.layer.cornerRadius = 20
    circleView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
    insertSubview(circleView!, atIndex: 0)

    isCellSelected = true
}
```

Here is my code for `didSelectItemAtIndexPath`:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "EEEE MMMM dd, yyyy"

    var dateString = ""
    if let newDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateFromComponents(monthComponentsByDay[indexPath.row]) {
        dateString = dateFormatter.stringFromDate(newDate)
        delegate?.dateSelected(newDate)
    }

    if currentCell != nil {
        currentCell!.deselect()
        currentCell = nil
    }


    dateLabel.text = dateString

    currentCell = collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? CalendarCollectionViewCell
    currentCellIndex = indexPath.row

    currentCell!.select()
}
```

I have tried `collectionView.selectItemAtIndexPath(indexPath:animated:scrollPosition:)` then manually calling the code to select, but the cell has not completely loaded at that time. I tried calling this in `cellForItemAtIndexPath` and `viewDidLoad` of the view controller with no luck.

Any suggestions on how to select an cell on load would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting the data that the view is building from?

Comment: @Mikael at the moment it is locally stored json file (test data).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `selectedBackgroundView` to indicate selection of your `cell`. Here is the description of that property:

> If `selectedBackgroundView` is different than `backgroundView`, it will be placed above the background view and animated in on selection.